# Как сделать обработку чисел aiogram

Tags: telegram-bot, aiogram

Я создаю своего телеграм-бота с товарами - и у меня есть такой вопрос: мне надо узнавать какое число напишет пользователь и преобразовывать его.
То есть мой бот пишет: "✏️ Введите сумму для пополнения баланса в рублях."   Я ввожу, допустим, `100` - и потом бот должен написать: ": Теперь отправь деньги на данные реквизиты: (карта)  Сумма: (число которое я написал) руб.".

Comment: Вопрос "как" в данном случае неуместен, так как не приведено никаких попыток решения. Что вы делали и что у вас не получилось?

Comment: Я не очень расбераюсь в телеграм ботах мне друг делал . В ютубе решения не нашел поэтому написал сюда, вопрос как по мне очень понятен. Бы ли бы попытки решения я бы сюда не писал) Я пытался сделать так: @dp.message_handler(answer)
async def answer(message : types.Message):
  if message.chat.type == 'private':
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,": Теперь отправь деньги на данные реквизиты: (карта) \n Сумма: answer руб \n Отправь сюда в чат скриншот чека:")

Comment: Чтобы писать ботов надо хотя бы понимать основы python. Используйте `int` для преобразования строки в число и используйте `try...except`, для того чтобы проверять на то что это число.

Comment: Спасибо а можете написать полную строку так сказать скопировать вставить) И бота не я делал друг подарил я начал добавлять новые функции просто